# AdBlock ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT .../devextreme/events/dblclick.js

Tags: angular, adblock, devextreme

I've tried to use [devextreme-angular](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-angular) in my angular 2 SPA.
But when I add dx to my project it stopped running in Chrome with AdBlock (in private mode or in other browsers it works fine).

It seems that `dblclick.js` caused this problem, like on this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHtwZ.png).

Can you please suggest me something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AdBlock blocking just one file, that required by SystemJS, but i suppose you will use bundle in production, created by WebPack or some else, so this problem will not reproduced for your customers.